# Indepedent Continuous Random Variable Question - Showing that LHS = RHS

Tags: statistics

I don't understand this. I'm struggling, bit by bit, to understand some of this material (I've asked a few questions already on these topics) but it feels like a slow grind and I'd rather not wait until tomorrow for my TAs to answer my question.

Suppose that X and Y are independent continuous random variables. Show that

a) $P(X + Y \leq a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_x(a - y)f_y(y)\ dy$

b) $P(X \leq Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_x(y)f_y(y)\ dy$

where $f_y$ is the density function of $Y$, and $F_x$ is the distribution function of $X$.

I just don't know where to start. An explanation would be very nice so I know how to tackle future problems of this type.

Comment: Are you familiar with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution a) follows from the convolution of (the distributions of) $X$ and $Y$, and b) follows from the convolution of $X$ and $-Y$.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Can you elaborate and/or give an example detailing how I would use it?